# doctrine migration: default value for not nullable fk

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, migration, default

I have an existing entity in database. I would like to add a new column to this entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $language;
```

When I now use `"vendor/bin/doctrine-migrate migrations:diff"`, the generated migration script does not contain a default value for `language_id`. Therefore the migration-script fails. Setting a default value for the property in the object does not help. How can I define a default value for the fk-column? I neither found something in doctrines documentation nor through google/stackoverflow.

Comment: To enhance my request: Here the exact message when running the migration script:

`An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE registered_user ADD language_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL':  
  SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column "language_id" contains null values `

Answer (score 1):

If the column is not null then it should represent a valid relationship; assuming you use `0` instead, Doctrine will try to load the association using that, which would of course fail. In these cases you *would* need to update the database and mapping to allow a null value.

If however you require a default *language* association to be defined then you explicitly need to set it when you create the entity.

```
$language = $entityManager->find(1);

$entity = new Entity;
$entity->setLanguage($language);

$entityManager->persist($entity);
$entityManager->flush();
```

For this reason, you might want to consider a 'service' that encapsulates the creation of your entity so you know a language will always be *valid* and assigned by default.

Comment: The problem I have is not related to new entries, but to already existing. The generated migration script does not contain a default value for language_id but it contains a not null constraint. Therefore the migration fails.

`An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE registered_user ADD language_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL':  
  SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column "language_id" contains null values`

Answer (score 1):

It may not be a clean way to do it, but maybe you can execute the SQL query yourself and add manually the DEFAULT statement ?

`ALTER TABLE registered_user ADD language_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT {default_value} WITH VALUES;`

I'm quite surprised that adding a default property in the annotation is not working here!

Comment: I've now tried this solution. The problem: When generating the next migration script, the default value would get deleted.

Comment: Yes, this is just to add your column and update your existing rows. I don't really know why, but I also found out that Doctrine does not manage default value SQL side. You have to set your default value in your entity constructor to be sure it will always exists (entity persisted or not). If this default value depends on a config parameter, I suggest you to use a manager (service) to create your entity, like suggested in the answer above.